# how to open multiple dropdowns from database. How do i assign unique IDs to each fetched dropdown button

Tags: php

I need to open multiple dropdowns that are being fetched from database inside a while loop. How do i assign unique IDs to each fetched dropdown button.

here is the Javascript code.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
var dropdowns = document.getElementByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
  }
   }    
  }
  </script>

   And this is HTML
   <table><tr><td>
    <a href="userprofile.php?id=<?php echo $r['id']; ?>"></td>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <td><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img 
    src="images/options.png" width="12" height="12" align="right"> 
    </button> 
    </td>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
   <td><div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">

   <a 
  href="#onclick="document.getElementById('debate').style.display='inline- 
   block'"><table><tr><td><img src="images/debates.png" width="20" 
   height="20"></td><td>Debate This!</td></tr></table></a>
   <a href="#"><table><tr><td><img src="images/flag.png" width="20" 
   height="20"></td><td>Report.</td></tr></table></a>
   </div> </div></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: I don't see where you "fetch drop-down button". Also I don't see what you question has to do with php. I guess you will need to be more specific about what you have done and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @user3190433 please look the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

how about (pure html no js ):

```
$data  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id='$someid');//or whatever query the point is that $data is array fetch from database 
print "<select name='dropdown'>";
for($i=0; $i <=count($data)-1; $i++) {
    print "<option value='$i'>$data[$i]['some_field']</option>"; // you can change $i with $data[$i]['primary_key_field']
}
print "</select>";
```